# Hausman Test intuition

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, econometrics, instrumental-variables, endogeneity

I don't understand why after plugging the residual from running the endogenous variable on instrument and other variables into the structural equation, we can tell whether the suspected endogenous variable is actually endogenous or not.

My confusion stems from the fact that even the coefficient of the residual-hat is significant, wouldn't that only mean that it's significant in explaining the dependent variable y? But we are interested in the Cov(x,residual hat)? Why couldn't we just run a regression between X and the residual hat to determine this relationship? Why do we have to plug the residual back into the structural equation?

Please help I've been thinking about this for 3 days. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider, based on the exposition in Wooldridge's panel data book, the model
\begin{equation}
y_{1i}=z_{i1}'\delta+\alpha y_{2i}+u_i
\end{equation}
We suspect $y_{2i}$ to be endogenous. Assume $z_{i1}$ is exogenous. We have at least one more valid instrument not contained in $z_{i1}$. The union of all
instruments is denoted by $x_i$. Now, write the linear projection of $y_{2i}$ on $x_i$ as
\begin{equation}
y_{2i}=x_i'\pi+v_i,
\end{equation}
so that $E(x_iv_i)=0$. As $u_i$ is uncorrelated with $x_i$, it follows from
$$
E(y_{i2}u_i)=E[(x_i'\pi+v_i)u_i]=E[v_iu_i],
$$
that $y_{2i}$ is endogenous if and only if $$E(u_iv_i)\neq 0.$$

This observation motivates the test. Write down the linear projection
\begin{equation}
u_i=\rho v_i+e_i,
\end{equation}
so that, by properties of linear projection coefficients, $$\rho=E(u_iv_i)/E(v_i^2)$$ and $$E(v_ie_i)=0.$$ $y_{2i}$ is endogenous if and only if $\rho\neq 0$. Inserting the equation for $u_i$ into the structural model
yields
\begin{equation}
y_{1i}=z_{i1}'\delta+\alpha y_{2i}+\rho v_i+e_i
\end{equation}
Rearranging $u_i=\rho v_i+e_i$ yields
$$
E[e_ix_i]=E[(u_i-\rho v_i)x_i].
$$
Due the exogeneity of $x_i$, $e_i$ is uncorrelated with $x_i$. As $u_i=\rho v_i+e_i$ is a linear projection, the same goes for $v_i$. Hence, $e_i$ is also uncorrelated with $y_{2i}$.

We could therefore test $H_0:\rho=0$ with a simple $t$-test in the regression $y_{1i}=z_{i1}'\delta+\alpha y_{2i}+\rho v_i+e_i$. This regression can however of course not be implemented as it stands, as $v_i$ is unobservable. But, we can get estimates $\widehat{v}_i$ through an OLS-regression for
$$
y_{2i}=x_i'\pi+v_i.
$$
This then yields the estimating equation
$$
y_{1i}=z_{i1}'\delta+\alpha y_{2i}+\rho\widehat{v}_i+\tilde{e}_i,
$$
for which the estimated coefficients are consistent for the respective parameters. One can show that $H_0:\rho=0$ can be tested with the usual (or, if necessary, with the heteroskedasticity robust) $t$-statistic of $\widehat{\rho}$.

(We estimate the equation with a *generated regressor* $\widehat{v}_i$. This usually has implications for inference; but not here as the generated regressor does not enter the model under $H_0$. See Wooldridge (Cross-Section and Panel Data Econometrics) for details.)

In plain English: We break up $y_{2i}$ into a part ($x_i$) that is uncorrelated with $u_i$ and one that may (endoneity) or may not (no endogeneity) correlate with $u_i$ ($v_i$). The former is the case if $\rho\neq0$, which may be tested once we have obtained the observable counterpart to $v_i$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'm still confused on a few points. It seems to me that in this explanation there's an extra step of regressing the structural error on reduced form error to come up with a correlation coefficient. However the notes I have for Hausman test only involves 2 steps : first we regress endogenous x on IV to come up with residual hat, secondly, we run the original regression with residual hat plugged in. I'm still confused as to why by running original regression on residual hat we can determine endogeneity?

Comment: You are right, I am sorry if my exposition has been confusing. The "extra" regression is one that is not run in practice, but serves to conceptually illustrate why conducting the t-test based on the final regression is legit. As to your final point, please refer to my edit at the end of the answer.

Comment: Is it fair to say that since the residual hat is essentially observed $y_{2i}$ - predicted $y_{2i}$ (this is the suspected part of $y_{2i}$ that's correlated with $u_i$)  so by plugging this into the structural equation we are essentially trying to see if we had an omitted variable that was left in the original error term. Namely $v_i$. If the coefficient for $v_i$ is significant, this means that we indeed had an omitted variable in the structural equation that we didn't account for.

Comment: In fact now that $v_i$ is in the structural equation this provides us a $β_{2sls}$ that is better than the original structural $β_{OLS}$ which implies our $β_{OLS}$ was inconsistent due to the presence of endogeneity ?  Furthermore, since we showed  $v_i$ is related to  $y_{2i}$, and $v_i$ is the omitted variable, by extension $y_{2i}$ must be endogenous to original error $u_i$ ?? 

Many thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: Yes, I think these are also useful ways to view the issue.